# Div dentro de ul

Tags: html

Quisiera saber si es correcto colocar un `div` dentro de un `ul`?
Tengo una barra de navegación realizada con un `ul - li` y agregué un botón que se diferencia al resto de los links, por eso quiero hacerlo con un `div`.
¿Es correcto?

Answer (score 0):

No creo que este mal porque todo va de acuerdo a como lo quieres plasmar, pero si se ve extraño.

Mas fácil, puedes colocar otro elemento li pero añadiéndole una clase

```
<li class="elemento"></li>
```

Luego con CSS le das el estilo que desees para que se vea diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Semanticamente no es correcto. Es preferible que modifiques las propiedades css de tus `li` recuerdo que esto por defecto tienen la propiedad `display: list-item` mientras el `div` tiene la propiedad `display: block` lo cual mas adelante va a producir errores de desbordamiento.

Una forma de corregir esto puede ser lo siguiente: (asumiendo tienes una clase que apunta en tu nav bar llamada `nav-bar`)

```css
ul.nav-bar > li {
   display: inline-block
}
```

> Disculpa por los acentos tengo mi ambiente en ingles.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las respuestas!